# didSelectItemAt IndexPath not pushing controller (but does get called)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have made a request to push navigationController to a new viewController when an item in my UICollectionView has been selected. The code runs but the action isn't performing. didSelectItemAt is being called however, as I checked this by requesting the colour changes when selected (which executes). The idea is to click on someone who has sent a message (chat function) and be sent to the collection of messages they have sent me. This project is done programmatically! Any ideas?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let controller = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    controller.match = messages?[indexPath.item].match
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)


    let cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
}
```

for further context, here is my AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = MatchesController()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Check if `navigationController` is `nil`.

Comment: this is pretty confusing, you're talking about performing segue and pushing a view controller, update your question to clarify

Comment: yea sorry, typo. I have updated OP

Comment: @PGDev how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit based on your comment below:**

since it's created programmatically so you need to include you `MatchesController` in a navigation stack:

so in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MatchesController())

window?.rootViewController = navigationController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

then you can push your `ChatLogController` from your `MatchesController()`

Comment: will this still be appropriate if I am looking to click on a sender (chat function) and be sent to a viewcontroller containing the messages they have sent me ? (sorry context I should have included, I will edit OP)

Comment: in the question's title you refer to `performSegue`, in the body you refer to `pushViewController`, you need to clarify that

Comment: whoops, thanks that was a typo, I have changed title

Comment: ok, so my answer is not good anymore. `ChatLogController` is created programmatically or in storyboard?

Comment: Gotcha, yea so the entire project is done programmatically (just updated OP again)

Comment: thanks for updating, really appreciated - so I currently have        

 window = UIWindow()
 window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 window?.rootViewController = MatchesController()

In my AppDelegates didFinishLaunchingWithOptions func, where MatchesController() is where my collectionView is

where would I then need to set up the below code in MatchesController() ?

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourCurrentViewController)

Comment: @Chakeeel i've edited, let me know if I understood correctly your issue

Comment: thanks for getting back quickly, so in response to what you put as your answer, I've had that in my AppDelegate since the start of the project so still confused, I'll update my OP again with app delegate so you can see if there are any issues there, but I can't see any - must be an issue in my collection view?

Comment: could it be an issue with 'let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout' ? I have stated this elsewhere, such as when I set up my matchesCollection programmatically

Comment: ChatLogController is a standard viewController?

Comment: ChatLogController is UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Comment: the problem is in this line of code here "navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)" - because if I change that line to this "let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller) present(navController, animated: true)" it executes

Comment: have you replaced your code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with the code I posted?

Comment: Hey Alastar, I did earlier but the screen just went black, I tried again  with "window = UIWindow()" included and works perfect ! Thanks :) I'll upvote you

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether "navigationController" is not nil? (One more thing pushViewController is different from performing segue.)